# SonarQube: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: android-studio, java, jvm, sonarqube

I'm new to SonarQube, When i run "C:\sonarqube-8.5.1.38104\bin\windows-x86-64\StartSonar.bat", i receives below error,

--> Wrapper Started as Console

```
Launching a JVM...
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024M
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2020.11.16 13:40:45 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\sonarqube-8.5.1.38104\temp
2020.11.16 13:40:45 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2020.11.16 13:40:45 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\sonarqube-8.5.1.38104\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube-8.5.1.38104\temp -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log -Xmx512m -Xms512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\sonarqube-8.5.1.38104\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=C:\sonarqube-8.5.1.38104\temp\conf\es -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
2020.11.16 13:40:45 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024M
Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
2020.11.16 13:40:46 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2020.11.16 13:40:46 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2020.11.16 13:40:46 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
FATAL StatusLogger Interrupted before Log4j Providers could be loaded.
 java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:159)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:372)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.lazyInit(ProviderUtil.java:121)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.hasProviders(ProviderUtil.java:108)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.unit.ByteSizeValue.<clinit>(ByteSizeValue.java:39)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkService.<clinit>(NetworkService.java:57)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportSettings.<clinit>(TransportSettings.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.newPluginService(TransportClient.java:105)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:135)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:277)
    at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl$MinimalTransportClient.<init>(EsConnectorImpl.java:103)
    at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl.buildTransportClient(EsConnectorImpl.java:89)
    at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl.getTransportClient(EsConnectorImpl.java:74)
    at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl.getClusterHealthStatus(EsConnectorImpl.java:61)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.checkStatus(EsManagedProcess.java:88)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.checkOperational(EsManagedProcess.java:73)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.isOperational(EsManagedProcess.java:58)
    at org.sonar.application.process.ManagedProcessHandler.refreshState(ManagedProcessHandler.java:220)
    at org.sonar.application.process.ManagedProcessHandler$EventWatcher.run(ManagedProcessHandler.java:285)
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
```

<-- Wrapper Stopped

Please help me here...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem most likely occurs due to the fact that you are attempting to run SonarQube with an unsupported Java version.

From the error log, I presume that you are attempting to run it using either Java 14 or Java 15 based on these lines:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024M
Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

The CMS collector was deprecated in Java 9 and removed altogether in Java 14:

https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/363

This means that the batch script that attempts to start Sonar is passing in some JVM args that are no longer valid.

Based on their documentation that only supported Java version are 8 and 11

https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/requirements/

and version above those are not supported:

> SonarQube scanners require version 8 or 11 of the JVM and the
> SonarQube server requires version 11. Versions beyond Java 11 are not
> officially supported.

I suggest you attempt to run it using the correct Java version. Also please check the related documentation beforehand to avoid such issues.

Comment: yes your are absolutely right, I also faced the same issue after when I installed JDK 11 TO 16  after uninstalling the latest version works smoothly,  but the reason why I switched 11 to 16 is the error "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0"